# Finding a permutation given a composite of permutations

Tags: abstract-algebra

Given the permutations $x = (1, 2)(3, 4)$ and $y = (5, 6)(1, 3)$ find a permutation $a$ such that $a^{−1}xa = y$.

I have an answer to this but I would like to know the process involved in getting the answer.

My thoughts thus far are that $a^{-1}(12)(34)a =(56)(13)$ which means that $a^{-1}((12)(34)a) =(56)(13)$. So $(a^{-1}(1(a)), a^{-1}(2(a))) (a^{-1}(3(a)), a^{-1}(4(a))) = (5,6)(1,3)$.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let $\sigma=[i_1,\ldots, i_n]$ be a cycle.  Use the fact that $\tau\sigma\tau^{-1}=[\tau(i_1),\ldots,\tau(i_n)]$.  So, what permutation takes $1$ to $5$, $2$ to $6$, $3$ to $1$ and $4$ to $3$.  The inverse of this permutation is the answer.

To find this, we can expess it as a matrix:
$$a^{-1}=\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 \\
5 & 6 & 1 & 3 & c & d
\end{pmatrix}$$

Here the image of a number in the first row, is the corresponding number in the second row.

We see that there are two possibilities, $c=2$, $d=4$ and $c=4$,$d=2$.

Let's take the case, $c=2$ and $d=4$.

So,
$$a^{-1}=\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 \\
5 & 6 & 1 & 3 & 2 & 4
\end{pmatrix}$$

and, 
$$a=\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6\\
3 & 5 & 4 & 6 & 1 & 2
\end{pmatrix}$$

Writing these as cycles gives:
$$a=(134625)\quad\text{and}\quad a^{-1}=(152643).$$

Comment: I understand that this would be how to find the answer but my book doesn't explain how to find the permutation from $1$  to $5$, $2$ to $6$, $3$ to $1$ and $4$ to $3$. It skipped over this.

Comment: OK.  I'll expand my answer.

Comment: I found so far that $(1234)(56)(12)(34) = (56)(13)$

Comment: Ok that makes a lot more sense. I didn't know you could do it that way.

Comment: Yeah, that matrix notation is quite handy. :)

Comment: Having a slight issue. If I have to check that this is true, I am not getting that $a^{-1}xa = y$. Is there some order in which I have to do this?

Comment: Don't forget to take the inverse.

Comment: I did. I got that $a=(1543)(26),a^{-1} = (1345)(26)$

Comment: I'll give you some more details.

Comment: Thank you. When I physically write it out in matrix form, it isn't working out for whatever reason. Your answer is correct though and I found it on my own as well.

Comment: Ok I see. So there are two possibilities and the one I chose was the one that doesn't work. That makes perfect sense. Thank you so much for being so thorough.